# Protect a server folder from non-logged in Wordpress users

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I have wordpress site that hides certain links in its post to non logged in users. The links go to a folder stored on the server (nothing too do with wp-uploads, all uploaded manually). For example -

http://domain.com/courses/course-one/index.html

I would like to secure the http://domain.com/courses folder so anyone typing or pasting the link in directly, or coming from another site has no access to the files inside.

Is it possible to only allow access to users who are currently logged into the site?
Or maybe the link only works if clicked from the site pages itself?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.willmaster.com/blog/contentprotection/htaccess-cookie.php

Comment: This is great thank you. I can set my own cookie for logged in users and test for it in the htaccess. Spot on!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of doing it

## Using cookies

As funkysouls suggested, we can create a .htaccess file to check if the user is loged in. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

This .htaccess file simply checks if the user have a cookie named "wordpress_logged_in". If there is no "wordpress_logged_in" cookie, then a 403 - forbiten page is shown.

The problem with this approach is that cookies can be created and modified by the client. In other words, the user can simply open browser's storage, create a cookie with this name, and access your protected files without login to wordpress.

## Using a PHP script

Another solution is to use .htaccess file to "redirect" to a php script. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$
RewriteRule . http://<HOST>/<YOUR-PHP-FILE>.php?file=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
```

Note that we pass the file name (`REQUEST_FILENAME`) to our php file through query params.

At the php file, you can check for user permissions and provide the file to the user:

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );

# load wordpress functions. We need that to retrive loged user information
include('../../wp-load.php');

# get filename from query params
$filename = $_GET['file'];

# check if user is loged in
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$can_access = ($user_level > 1);

# You could also check if the user is an adm
# $is_adm = current_user_can('administrator');


# Clean buffer management (prevent erros at file "generation")
while (ob_get_level()) {
   ob_end_clean();
}

if ($can_access){
        header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filename));

        $read = readfile($filename);

        if (!$read){
                echo "error while loading the file";
        }
}else{
        echo "you can not access this file";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, @giusti. I edited my answer to make it look less like another question.

Comment: Hi, @Anny. Perhaps I made a mistake. Thanks for letting me know.